# Using html inside double quoted echos

Tags: php, html

I want to change the colour of some text and it has to be inside double quotation marks as it is a variable. This is the only instance in which it happens so I won't bother with CSS.

```
  echo "$playername ";
```

I tried

```
echo "<font color="yellow"> $playername </font>" ;
```

But it is not working, I assume this is because it does not like double quotes inside double quotes. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: `echo "<font color=\"yellow\"> $playername </font>" ;` or `echo '<font color="yellow"> $playername </font>' ;`

Comment: There's so many ways to solve this. I know this is a dupe. Just gotta find the right one.

Comment: Side note, `<font>` doesn't exist anymore so don't use it

Comment: Not all attributes need to be quoted. (XHTML is not a thing anymore). `"<font color=yellow>…"` also would do. (Though again, `<font>` is very outdated.)

Comment: just try: echo '<font color="yellow"> $playername </font>';

Comment: Double quotes inside double quotes break your string, so you must use escape character like backslash for double quotes \"
Also change font and color to span and style. $playername is variable so need to use concatenation operator (.) to add it to string.

    echo "<span style=\"color: yellow;\">".$playername."</span>";

Comment: I'd like to advocate reopening this question because it is not simply a PHP question.  It raises questions about what is valid HTML as pertaining to attributes as well as the FONT tag.

Answer (score 0):

The necessity of quoted attribute values only comes into play when dealing with values that may contain contain whitespace or characters meaningful to HTML, such as "<".  So, in this case, the OP does not need to quote the attribute value; see [here](https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/unquoted-attribute-values).

If one insists on quoting an attribute value, one may use single quotes or else quote double quotes as in below example:

```
<?php 
$playername = "Nobody";
$yellow="\"yellow\"";
echo "<font color=$yellow>$playername</font>";
```

Note: while the FONT tag is [obsolete](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/font), it nonetheless works at any rate in my version of Google Chrome (YMMV). Note, the [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/font) adamantly discourages using the FONT tag:

> Do not use this element! Though once normalized in HTML 3.2, it was
>   deprecated in HTML 4.01, at the same time as all elements related to
>   styling only, then obsoleted in HTML5.