# How to use ' and " in PHP string?

Tags: php

I'm currently trying to implement a self hosted video player into an existing script, however the code required includes both ' and " how would I implement this into my PHP code ?

```
$html .= '<video id="vid1" class="video-js" controls="" preload="auto" data-setup="{}"><source src="'.$Player['URL'].'" poster="'.$Poster['URL'].'" type="video/mp4"></video>';
```

This works perfectly fine as is, however I'm needing this additional code implemented into the video player, but as I mentioned above it includes ' and " which makes it very difficult to implement.

```
data-setup='{
            "plugins": {
                    "vastClient": {
                    "adTagUrl": "AD TAG"
                }
            }}'
```

The main chunk of PHP cannot be rewritten as it would take far too long, I'm sure there's a solution which I'm looking over.

Any help or ideas would be fantastic thanks.

I have tried replacing ' with " which results in an error, I have also tried /' which has the same result.

Comment: The escape character is \`\\` not `/`, but the code above should work fine as it is.

Comment: [Using html inside double quoted echos](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55248214/2943403)  Maybe worth a read: https://stackoverflow.com/q/8542746/2943403 and https://stackoverflow.com/q/15838593/2943403

Comment: TBH it looks like you should use `data-setup="' .htmlspecialchars(json_encode(['plugins' => ... ])).'"`

Comment: Good advice @Phil, I added three more dupes that demonstrate that advice.

Answer (score 0):

Simpliest way to use both `'` and `"`, [use heredoc/nowdoc](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc).

Comment: Multi-duplicate questions do not need new answers to resolve the page.  Please help to reduce redundant content by closing pages that should be closed instead of answering them.